# Data insertion in Sql Table is taking too much time

Tags: sql-server, c#-4.0, foreach, progress-bar

I am inserting data in the sql server.Here is the code:

```
SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[1];
            param[0] = new SqlParameter();
            param[0].ParameterName = "@Exch";
            param[0].SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
            param[0].Value = "BSE";
            formObjSqlConnection.SQLConnection.Executes("LPExch..DeleteVarMargin", param);
            foreach (BseVar objBseVar in objListNseData)
            {

                currentIndex++;
                param = new SqlParameter[10];
                param[0] = new SqlParameter();
                param[0].ParameterName = "@Exch";
                param[0].SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Char;
                param[0].Value = "BSE";

                param[1] = new SqlParameter();
                param[1].ParameterName = "@Symbol";
                param[1].SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Char;
                param[1].Size = 10;
                param[1].Value = objBseVar.Symbol;



                param[2] = new SqlParameter();
                param[2].ParameterName = "@Series";
                param[2].SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Char;
                param[2].Value = "EQ";

                param[3] = new SqlParameter();
                param[3].ParameterName = "@SecurityVar";
                param[3].SqlDbType = SqlDbType.SmallMoney;

                param[3].Value = objBseVar.SecurityVar;

                param[4] = new SqlParameter();
                param[4].ParameterName = "@IndexVar";
                param[4].SqlDbType = SqlDbType.SmallMoney;

                param[4].Value = 0;


                param[5] = new SqlParameter();
                param[5].ParameterName = "@VarMargin";
                param[5].SqlDbType = SqlDbType.SmallMoney;

                param[5].Value = objBseVar.IndexVar;

                param[6] = new SqlParameter();
                param[6].ParameterName = "@AdhocMargin";
                param[6].SqlDbType = SqlDbType.SmallMoney;

                param[6].Value = objBseVar.SecurityVar - objBseVar.IndexVar;


                param[7] = new SqlParameter();
                param[7].ParameterName = "@VarMarginRate";
                param[7].SqlDbType = SqlDbType.SmallMoney;

                param[7].Value = objBseVar.IndexVar;

                formObjSqlConnection.SQLConnection.Executes("LPExch..UpdateOrAddCashVarMarginBSE", param);
                if (Convert.ToInt32(1 / progressChange * currentIndex) <= 100)
                    objImportMaster.UpdateProgressBar(Convert.ToInt32(1 / progressChange * currentIndex));
            }
            formObjSqlConnection.SQLConnection.Executes("LPExch..UpdateCashVarMarginBSEScripNo");
```

Is there any other way i can insert the data in the database.The problem is that database is taking too much time to insert the data.Also i am updating the progressbar in other UI.
Is that the reason for slow insertion?
Can we use any other way to insert data.?

Comment: You could remove the creation of the parameters from the loop and updating only the values at each loop. But I don't think you could have a significant gain. The best option is using a [Table Valued Param](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx)

Comment: Kindly help me in speeding up the data insertion.

Comment: @ Steve How can i write the same for this loop.Using  Table Valued Param.

Comment: I can only offer you a link to an example. Many things depend on your own situation and only you could choose the best path. Look at [this example](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2112/table-value-parameters-in-sql-server-2008-and-net-c/) or search for 'C# using Table Valued Parameters"

Comment: @ Steve Thank you sir.I got the hint rest i will try.If any issues will surely contact you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you are sending every insert one at a time. That's slow. If you can change the database, look up [table valued parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx) and pass a table to your function so you can send all the records just once.

If you have direct access to a table, you can also use [bulk copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx).

Comment: How to implement the same in this case.Kindly guide me.I read the link but could not find a way to implement it. :(

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to insert many records then consider using bulk copy, it is quite fast.
An example is available [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16922/SQL-Bulk-Copy-with-C-Net).